# Moving a table row by row each time the form is submitted on same page

Tags: php

I have a table with rows of countries, names, etc

I also have a form with processes each row

I need to submit the form on the same page

How do I get to the next row of the same table on the same page

Do I use while, or foreach, where do I put the closing `}` or is there another way?

Comment: I've read your question again, do you mean: I edit row in the form, submit and then the form must be filled with the next row's data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i made a start for you. I think you want to list all the rows from the db into an HTML table with an form at the bottom to add a new row to the db, right?

If so, then you can do it with this single PHP page code. Please note that i'm not considering any security for safe queries! You can find more about that on the Internet.

```
<?php
    $DB_NAME = 'DATABASE_NAME';
    $DB_HOST = 'DATABASE_HOST';
    $DB_USER = 'DATABASE_USER';
    $DB_PASS = 'DATABASE_PASSWORD';

    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    //form submit?
    if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
        //INSERT QUERY
        $q = "INSERT INTO `your_table`(`field1`, `field2`, `field3`) VALUES ('" . $_POST['field1'] . "', '" . $_POST['field2'] . "', '" . $_POST['field3'] . "')";
        $mysqli->query($q) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    }

    //get all items from db (also the new row)
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `your_table`";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    //build first part of table
    echo '<table>
            <thead>
                <th>
                    <td>Your field1</td>
                    <td>Your field2</td>
                    <td>Your field3</td>
                </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';

    //create rows
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>' . $row['field1'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row['field2'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row['field3'] . '</td>
                 </tr>';    
        }
    } else {
        echo '<tr><td colspan=3>NO RESULTS</td></tr>';  
    }

    //close table
    echo '      </tbody>
          </table>';

    // CLOSE CONNECTION
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>

<!-- the form -->
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <input type="text" name="field3" />

    <input type="submit" name="save" value="save" />
</form>
```

Hopes this helps!